# What are the mitzvot that require intent?

Tags: mitzvah, kavana-intent

Forgive me in that I do not know the proper nomenclature.

Some mitzvot are complete by the simple action (or refrain from action)

Some mitzvot require action and intent, besides the problem of intent to make a Mitzva: what are these called? some examples?

Are there also mitzvot that require intent, but not action? (if so, what are they called, and an example or two?)

Comment: by 'intent' do you include any mental component?

Comment: See Sefer Chatedim. I don't know if it os translated. The last parag. of the Q ... Obviously yes concerning Emuna for positive m. an AZ for negative one. The fact that you ask for negative mitsva for intent is really very interesting.

Comment: One that I am aware of, as it is approaching - one must have intent, meaning understanding of the reason for the mitzvah - when eating / dwelling in the succah.