# Does the observance of Shabbat require kavannah?

Tags: shabbat, intent-accident-purposely

I am trying to understand what it means to "keep shabbat" completely. It appears that there are [two](http://www.practicalhalacha.com/halacha.php?id=2518) general components, Shamor (refraining from the forbidden behaviors -- negative) and Zachor (engaging in proper behaviors, positive). Does the abiding by either of these general categories require [intent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76830/what-are-the-mitzvot-that-require-intent)/kavannah in order for it to be considered as having been "observed"?

I have read that in order to be guilty of trespass when performing a melacha, there is some need for intention on some level. But if I am not faced with a situation in which I can [winnow](https://www.ou.org/holidays/shabbat/melacha-6-winnowing/), then is my "not winnowing" (simply by circumstance and outside my awareness) an observance, or must I have in mind that I am refraining from each melacha? Or when an opportunity to winnow comes about, must my reasoning for not winnowing be related to its being Shabbat?

On the Zachor side, must I "enjoy" with an eye towards Shabbat? Aside from the Kiddush, candles, havdalah, there seems to be an obligation to have "oneg" and "kibud" but do those require intent? If I sit and eat tasty foods and put on special clothes, but only because I want to, not considering that it is Shabbat, have I fulfilled that aspect of Zachor? Have I been mechalel Shabbat, or not observed it in the "proper" way if I don't have Shabbat in mind when relaxing?

Ultimately, If I sleep through the entire 25 hour period, have I observed Shabbat in any proper sense (having done no melachot but without awareness of Shamor, and not having actively done "Zachor")?

Comment: How is this different from any other Mitzva, where we can debate in general if Mitzvot Tzerikhot Kavana or not?